# div inside another div positioning in center

Tags: html, css, position

I want to make a `div` which has two `div`s inside itself, and also I want to position them ALL in center using the `margin:auto` property. But it's not working properly. I've searched the web for this problem but I couldn't find a good answer. What have I missed?

```
<style>
        body{
            padding: 0px;
            margin:0px;
        }
        .top{
            padding: 0px;
            margin:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:50%;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        .top div{
            margin:auto;
            padding:0px;
            box-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            background-color: red;
            border-radius:20px;
        }
        .top div div{
            margin:auto;
            padding:0px;
            box-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: red;
            border-radius:20px;
        }
</style>
```

to whom asked for html:

```
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You also need to post the HTML structure; CSS on its own is not very meaningful.

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML Code or set up a code snippet on jsfiddle.net? It would be easier to help you.

Comment: It is aligning in horizontal center. do you need vertical centering also?

Comment: yes i need both horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update you following class. Please add positions to `.top div {position:relative;}` and update the `.top div div` class.

**Html**

```
<div class="top">
         <div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
body{
            padding: 0px;
            margin:0px;
        }
        .top{
            padding: 0px;
            margin:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:50%;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        .top div{
            margin:auto;
            padding:0px;
            box-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            background-color: red;
            border-radius:20px;
          position:relative;
        }
        .top div div{
            margin:auto;
            padding:0px;
            box-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: red;
            border-radius:20px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
```

Demo [here](http://codepen.io/fanafazil/pen/NNKdYw)